# How long will it take to get my passport back after withdrawing my uk visa application?

Tags: visas, uk

I applied for uk visa and submitted my passport and biometrics in Delhi. After three weeks I withdrew my application on their online portal. I submitted the withdrawal request Friday morning. How long will it take to get my passport back? I have a flight on Thursday! Please help.

Comment: You will find out shortly.

Comment: I doubt you’ll get it back in time

Answer (score -2):

I believe that the passports are actually, physically, sent to the United Kingdom where the visa application is processed and decided.

> [British Embassy Berlin - GOV.UK - Visas](https://www.gov.uk/world/organisations/british-embassy-berlin)
> UK Visas & Immigration (UKVI) is responsible for all Visa matters. The British Embassy **does not deal with visa services** and cannot advise you on visa matters.

(This probably does not apply for all countries)

Only special Visa Application Centres exist where a special, faster, service is available.

Assuming that this is correct and your withdrawal request was Friday morning (in India), the time needed to transport the passport from the UK to India per post (**after** the withdrawal request was processed in the UK (which may, or not, take place Friday morning UK time), packaged and sent off) would have to be calculated (assume that on the weekend nothing will happen).

After arrival back in India, further processing at the Visa Application Centre should be added to that time.

Six days (including the weekend), seems to me, to be unrealistic.

Comment: I called the embassy, they confirmed they send it to the local embassy so it’s in Delhi. Other than that they could not verify any other info!

Comment: @Jojo Do you mean local **consulate** or **Visa Application Centre**? You should add that information to your question. The report I read was a statement from the British Embassy in Berlin that the embassy and consulates in Germany don't process the applications and send everything to London. So that may be only true for Europe.

Comment: @Jojo When you withdrew your application, did you mention that you needed your passport back urgently? The likely processing timescale seems to be 10 working days, as this is stated here https://www.gov.uk/visa-documents-returned as the length of time that must have elapsed before you can report that you’ve not received your documents back https://eforms.homeoffice.gov.uk/outreach/Progress_enquiry.ofml?_ga=2.47506087.1240556281.1637657836-1958139047.1637093820

Comment: Why don't you personally visit the New Delhi embassy? They may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I managed to email the deputy commissioner at the UK high commission in delhi! Luckily she forwarded my email to their consular section and they emailed me back stating I must visit the visa application center in delhi and fill out the withdrawal form and that they would hand me my passport! I went there and waited until closing because that’s when their suitcases arrive from the uk high commission with passports ready for collection. So after a 3 hour drive from where I’m currently residing and a 4 hour wait i got my passport. But apparently the online info is not accurate!